# Rendering issues in FrozenLake-v1 environment

Tags: python, render, openai-gym, openai-api

I am using the `FrozenLake-v1` gym environment for testing q-table algorithms.
When I use the default map size 4x4 and call the `env.render()` function, I see the image as shown:

[[image: env.render() for 4x4 map]]

But when I call the same `env.render()` function for map size 8x8, I see no such results! The code runs fine with no error message, but the render window doesn't show up at all!

I have tried using the following two commands for invoking the gym environment:

```
env = gym.make("FrozenLake8x8-v1")

env = gym.make("FrozenLake-v1", map_name="8x8")
```

but still, the issue persists.

Any reason why the render window doesn't show up for any other map apart from the default 4x4 setting? Or am I making a mistake somewhere in calling the 8x8 frozen lake environment?

Link to the FrozenLake openai gym environment: https://gym.openai.com/envs/FrozenLake8x8-v0/

Answer (score 2):

How about using `print()` function? (BTW, my code only accepts this approach both for 4x4 and 8x8)

I'm doing my job with jupyter notebook, and the code below worked well. Hope this helps.

```
env = gym.make('FrozenLake8x8-v1', render_mode="ansi")
env.reset()
print(env.render())
```

You can check my environment and the result from below image. I used gymnasium v0.26.3 and Python v3.9.16.

[image: My setting and the result]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code, but add it in instead. :)

Comment: @juanpethes Oh code in the picture is the same as the written one. I posted the picture to 1) clarify my environment like gym version and python version, and 2) show the proper result. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: Oh alright no problem. I was kind of an NPC.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same problem. I was able to fix it by passing in  render_mode="human". For example

```
env = gym.make("FrozenLake-v1", map_name="8x8", render_mode="human")
```

This worked on my own custom maps in addition to the built in ones.